# Where is the runeforged weapon enchantment in Pathfinder

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, weapons

I have seen references to this enchantment in a few threads lately, but cannot seem to find it on the srd or anywhere else for that matter.  Any pointers as to its location would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Runeforged weapon enhancement is from the Rise of the Runelords adventure path, appropriately enough.  It was originally in the fifth volume, and can now be found in the reprinted, Pathfinder edition of the adventure path.